# Convert decimal to hex using PHP

Tags: php, hex, decimal

How to convert decimal value to hex using php?

Dec : `68-55-230-06-04-89`

I want `hex value` like this

Hex : `44-37-E0-06-04-59`  but instead of this its display `44-37-E0-6-4-59`

```
echo $test = dechex(68)."-".dechex(55)."-".dechex(230)."-".dechex(06)."-".dechex(04)."-".dechex(89);
```

It's give me output : `44-37-E0-6-4-59` // without 06-04

I want output something like `44-37-E0-06-04-59`

Comment: Print your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting `44-37-E0-06-04-59` just add `0` as below,

```
sprintf('%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X', 68, 55, 230, 06, 04, 89);
```

Comment: Be careful with 06 like numbers.

Comment: what about [2's compliment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952913/php-string-to-hex-with2s-complement)?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
sprintf('%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X', 68, 55, 230, 6, 4, 89);
```

Comment: what about [2's compliment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952913/php-string-to-hex-with2s-complement)?

Answer (score 1):

```
$dec= "68-55-230-06-04-89";

$arr= split("-",$dec);

foreach($arr as $key => $num)

{

    $arr[$key]=sprintf('%02X',dechex ($num));

}


//required results Array ( [0] => 44 [1] => 37 [2] => e6 [3] => 6 [04] => 4 [05] => 59 )

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: what about signed 2's compliment?

Answer (score 0):

something like that should work if you assume that there are maximum of FF between the dashes:

```
$foo = explode("-", $dec);
foreach ($foo as $dec_value) {
    echo ($dec_value > 16) ? dechex($dec_value) : "0".dechex($dec_value);
}
```