# php string to hex with2's complement:

Tags: php, string, hex

Hi I have a string `193390663` which I want to convert into the `hex` with `2's compliment`. The output is `0B86E847`

Right now I am using below function but it's giving me `313933333930363633`

```
 public static function String2Hex($string)
{
    $hex = '';
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        $hex.=dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

Tried this

```
 $sub2 = substr($m->msn,4,9);
            $m->m_hex = dechex ($sub2);
```

**Output**

```
b86e847
```

But I want output like `0B86E847`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @NigelRen So what is the correct way of getting `hex with 2's compliment` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution you are looking for is as below,

It is referenced from one of the answer given at [Create hex-representation of signed int in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135572/create-hex-representation-of-signed-int-in-php).

```
<?php

function signed2hex($value, $reverseEndianness = true)
{
    $packed = pack('i', $value);
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++){
        $hex .= strtoupper( str_pad( dechex(ord($packed[$i])) , 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) );
    }
    $tmp = str_split($hex, 2);
    $out = implode('', ($reverseEndianness ? array_reverse($tmp) : $tmp));
    return $out;
}

echo signed2hex(193390663);
```